# How to add onHover event to Google Map Marker? Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm using google_maps_flutter_web flutter's package and I only see onTap, onDrag and onDragged event available in Marker Widget. Are there anyway I could add a callback when I hovering my mouse over the Marker? Because the mouse cursor icon change when it's hovered.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLaTQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in `onHover` or `onMouseOver` methods for Google map [Markers](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Marker-class.html) on Flutter web and unfortunately, something like this is unlikely to be prioritized (a [similar feature request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82172) to add an onLongPress callback to markers is currently p5).

But, with a little ingenuity it's possible to implement this ourselves.

## 1. Wrap your GoogleMap widget with the [MouseRegion](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html) and [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) widgets

The MouseRegion widget will allow us to track the location of the user's mouse.

The LayoutBuilder widget will give us the dimensions of the GoogleMap so we can eventually translate the position of the mouse to a latitude and longitude on the map.

```dart
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
   return MouseRegion(
     child: GoogleMap(
       minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(10, 18)
       mapType: MapType.normal,
       initialCameraPosition: mapModel.initialMapLocation(),
       onMapCreated: (controller) {
          mapModel.onMapCreated(controller));
       },
       markers: markers
       ),
     );
  });
```

## 2. Create a variable to store the LatLng value of the mouse position

```
LatLng? hoverSpot;

void setHoverSpot(LatLng? val) {
    hoverSpot = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

## 3. Add an onHover callback to the MouseRegion widget

Whenever the user moves the mouse within the MouseRegion widget, the onHover callback will be called. This callback provides us with a PointerEvent object that holds the position data of the mouse.

This part is a little hairy but stay with me.

Our goal is to convert the local position of the mouse to a LatLng value we can plot on the map. The bulk of the work can be done by the [getLatLng](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/getLatLng.html) method of the GoogleMapController. All we have to do is give it a ScreenCoordinate.

```
 MouseRegion(
   onHover: (event) async {
     LatLng? position = await mapModel.mapController?.getLatLng(ScreenCoordinate(
      x: ((constraints.maxWidth) * (event.localPosition.dx / (constraints.maxWidth))).round(),
      y: ((constraints.maxHeight) * (event.localPosition.dy / constraints.maxHeight)).round(),
   ));

  mapModel.setHoverSpot(position);
                        
  },
  child: GoogleMap(
      ...
  ),
);
```

## 4. Calculate the distance between the hoverSpot and each of your markers

The [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) package has a distanceBetween method you can use to calculate the distance between 2 points.

Then based on the zoom level, you can determine if the distance is within an acceptable range to indicate the user is actually hovering over a given marker.

```
  Map<int, int> zoomToDistance = {
    10: 4600,
    11: 2400,
    12: 1250,
    13: 770, 
    14: 410, 
    15: 180, 
    16: 80, 
    17: 30, 
    18: 15,
  };

  Map<int, double> zoomToMarkerHeight = {
    10: .06,
    11: .03,
    12: .016,
    13: .009, 
    14: .005, 
    15: .002, 
    16: .0008, 
    17: .0004, 
    18: .0002,
  };

if (hoverSpot != null) {
          double distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
            hoverSpot!.latitude,
            hoverSpot!.longitude,
            markerLocation.latitude + zoomToMarkerHeight[currentZoomLevel]!,
            markerLocation.longitude,
          );

          // debugPrint('distance: ' + distance.toString());

          if (distance < zoomToDistance[currentZoomLevel]!) {
            selected = true;
            minDistance = distance;
            showInfoWindow(
                markerId: marker.id,
                latLng: LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude),
              );
          }
        }
```

## 5. Show the info window over the marker

https://gfycat.com/whisperedadmiredivorybilledwoodpecker